# Install apt-get package on yocto-linux bitbake failed

Tags: yocto, apt, bitbake, openembedded

Prerequisite:

- yocto thud
- local.conf

```
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL_append = " \                                                                                                                   
apt \                                                                                                                                  
"                                                                                                                                               
PACKAGE_CLASSES_append = " \                                                                                                                 
package_deb \                                                                                                                            
"
```

- ./poky/meta/recipes-devtools/apt_1.2.24.bb

With setting above, I want to install apt-get package manager to my Yocto.
However I got the error like below. It gave me warning messages about data dictionary file (d) from bitbake which did not being used.

```
...
In file included from /home/test/my-linux-board/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/apt/1.2.24-r0/apt-1.2.24/apt-pkg/policy.cc:18:
/home/test/my-linux-board/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/apt/1.2.24-r0/build/include/apt-pkg/policy.h:92:17: warning: private field 'd' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
   void * const d;
                ^
8 warnings generated.
6 warnings generated.
In file included from /home/test/my-linux-board/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/apt/1.2.24-r0/apt-1.2.24/apt-pkg/pkgcachegen.cc:15:
/home/test/my-linux-board/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/apt/1.2.24-r0/build/include/apt-pkg/pkgcachegen.h:162:17: warning: private field 'd' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
   void * const d;
                ^
/home/test/my-linux-board/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/apt/1.2.24-r0/build/include/apt-pkg/pkgcachegen.h:188:17: warning: private field 'd' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
   void * const d;
                ^
6 warnings generated.
7 warnings generated.
8 warnings generated.
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
makefile:18: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/test/my-linux-board/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/apt/1.2.24-r0/temp/log.do_compile.31530)
```

Just my assumption, maybe on package-deb "d" is not being used because the default setting of my PACKAGE_CLASSES is package_rpm.
Could somebody give me a hand to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: `IMAGE_FEATURES += " package-management"

Comment: I am sorry did not mentioned it before but condition above is with IMAGE_FEATURES holding package-management.
 
IMAGE_FEATURES_append = " \                                                                                   
    package-management \                                                                                      
"